# Why getting System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException when run my application in windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, httpclient, async-await

I am develop a WPF application which can communicate my server using Http Client.

My Application build on .NET 4. I install Http Client via nugget. I also install 
**Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack** via nugget.

In Windows 8 it works without any problem. But in Windows 7 I get an Exception

> Application: whost.Generator.Creator.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException Stack:
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   whost.Generator.Creator.Basic.ServerCommunicator.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> Exception rethrown at [1]:     at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   whost.Generator.Creator.ViewModel.LicenseGenerateViewModel.d_*3.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b*_0(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode,
>   CleanupCode, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at
>   whost.Generator.Creator.App.Main()

I don`t understand why I get this exception.
My Server is build on MVC 4 And WEB API.

Thanks in advance.

Update 1: 
       My Code Is:

```
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myhost.com/") };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var loginModel = new LoginModel
       {
         UserName = Username,
         Password = Password,
       };
    var userLoginResposnce = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("account/Login", loginModel);
    var successInfoTamplate = new { Success = true };
    var loginResponceString = await userLoginResposnce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var isSuccess = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(loginResponceString, successInfoTamplate);
```

I installed .NET 4 On My Windows 7 PC.

Comment: isn't it because of .net framework installed on your machine? did you update .net framework to the latest version on your windows 7?

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your code that is throwing the error?  The stack trace is great, but it's also pretty useless without the context (code) to go with it.